# Do While freq.Value <> " " 'if freq in range >< empty --> ERROR BUG

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on this excel doc at my internship for a researcher and can't seam to get this straight

```
Sub Boucle()

    Dim freq As Range
    Set freq = Range("D10:D230")

    Do While freq.Value <> " " 'if freq in range >< empty --> ERROR BUG HERE

        freq.Offset(0, 1).Copy 'copy value of adjacent cell 
        freq.Offset(freq.Value + 1, 18).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'and paste to specific value +1 into table I created

    Loop
End Sub
```

VBA says Runtime error 13 which is weird because when i do the same code with "For each cell" it works but gives me the paste of all values at the first freq.Value + 1

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Well `freq` is a bunch of cells so what value would `<> " "` compare against?

Comment: I just tried it myself and had no problem. Are you sure your quotes haven't been changed, due to locale settings?

Comment: Don't call your sub Loop, surprised that's even allowed, and you can't compare the whole range to a single value.

Comment: Thank you I solved my issue with the following For Each freq In Range("D10:D25")
    If freq.Value <> " " Then freq.Offset(0, 1).Copy
    Masking_threshold.Offset(freq.Value, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next

Comment: @SJR sorry i'm really new at this and just translated this from french for "boucle"

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Boucle()
    Dim freq As Range
    Set freq = Range("D10:D25")
    Set Masking_threshold = Cells(1, 21) '= column in which I wanted to paste

    For Each freq In Range("D10:D25")
        If freq.Value <> " " Then
              freq.Offset(0, 1).Copy
              Masking_threshold.Offset(freq.Value, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Somehow it worked fine with the same variables (range >< " ") for this argument.